# CSV Template File Reader

Tags: java, spring, spring-xd

In order to read csv files having certain information in header, how can we use templates to fetch the data from those files and persist data in database?

Currently, using normal file reader for line by line processing.

Comment: Check if [SuperCsv](http://www.codejava.net/coding/super-csv-reading-csv-files-into-pojos-with-csvbeanreader) is an option

Comment: This is not a standard csv, there is certain configuration information before actual csv data. Need to read that also. Is there anything to which we give input the file and it parses that according to the provided template ?